# See per-VM network usage in Xen Hypervisor (nethogs)

Tags: linux-networking, monitoring, xen, network-monitoring, utilization

How can I see my network utilization per-VM in realtime in Xen?

On a system, I can see the real-time, per-process utilization of my network using `nethogs`.

On my Xen system, there's `xentop`, but (even with the `-n` argument), I can't which VM is hogging my bandwidth. I'm using QubesOS.

Is there a command-line tool available on dom0 that I can run to see which AppVM is using lots of network bandwidth in real-time?